# schema-codegen failed: A required class was missing while executing

Tags: jibx

I am getting the below error while trying to build an application. This is failing while running tests otherwise it is fine :

```
    WARNING: Error injecting: org.jibx.maven.SchemaCodeGenMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jibx/runtime/JiBXException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2483)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1891)

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jibx:maven-jibx-plugin:1.2.2:schema-codegen (generate-java-code-from-xml-schema) on project b2bservices-xml-api: 
Execution generate-java-code-from-xml-schema of goal org.jibx:maven-jibx-plugin:1.2.2:schema-codegen failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jibx:maven-jibx-plugin:1.2.2:schema-codegen: org/jibx/runtime/JiBXException
```

My pom looks like :

```
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jibx-bind</artifactId>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jibx-run</artifactId>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>


<build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-jibx-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.2.2</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>generate-java-code-from-xml-schema</id>
                                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>schema-codegen</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <targetDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</targetDirectory>
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas</directory>
                                        <includes>
                                            <includes>xml_services.xsd</includes>
                                        </includes>
                                        <options>
                                            <package>com.company.b2c.product.xml</package>
                                            <prefer-inline>true</prefer-inline>
                                            <show-schema>true</show-schema>
                                            <binding-file-name>binding.xml</binding-file-name>
                                        </options>
                                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
```

Now this is getting failed during build process. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the JiBX dependencies in your pom file:

`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
  <artifactId>jibx-run</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
  <artifactId>jibx-extras</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>`

I would also recommend using a newer version of JiBX like 1.2.5.

Don Corley

JiBX contributor.

Comment: Hi Don thanks for the reply. But I have already specified these dependencies in my pom.